# Initialize() в Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Я начинал изучать`Framework MonoGame/XNA` языка **C#**,уже понимаю устройство программы,но не могу понять зачем нужен метод `Initialize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Initialize()` позволяет игре выполнять любую инициализацию, необходимую для ее запуска, прежде чем запускать ее. Это то, где он может запрашивать любые необходимые службы и загружать любой контент, не связанный с графикой. Вызов `base.Initialize` будет перечислять через любые компоненты и инициализировать их.Этот метод вызывается вскоре после конструктора перед запуском [игрового цикла](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/the-game-loop).
Это позволяет вам выполнять одноразовую инициализацию для вашей игры.

Comment: Хотелось бы еще спросить, а чем тогда конструктор отличается от инициализации, если так же могу инициализировать в конструкторе?